# Storing tables in client machine and synchronizing later

Tags: .net, sql, synchronization

I am developing "point of sale" application in Window platform, using VS 2010 and SQL Server 2005.

I want to store few tables in the client machine. I have a tag named `SynchronizeStatus` in XML file in my client machine.

After installing the setup, when user login, it will check the `SynchronizeStatus` in the XML file. If `SynchronizeStatus` is set to `true`, I want to import some tables to the client machine and user must be able to access data from the local only. If `SynchronizeStatus` is set to `false`, then I don't need to import any tables to client machine.

I have a column named `ModifiedDate` in all the synchronizing tables.

Next time when user logs in, I have to compare `ModifiedDate` from client side table and server side table. If server side `ModifiedDate` is greater then client side `ModifiedDate` then, my local tables have to synchronize with the server side tables or they have to fetch from the client machine itself.

Sometimes, manually I want to synchronize my client side data to server side data.

What is best way to store tables in client machine and to synchronize them? How do I do this?

I tried using `LocalDataCache`, but in vain.

Comment: Check out the Microsoft Sync Framework.

Comment: what did you run into using the Local Database Cache? its the easiest one to use for your scenario.

Comment: This article helped me to achieve my goal. Thanks chrisF anf JuneT  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938879.aspx